# Remove last part of link text mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with description column text :

```
    <center>
texttextffjfjfffkfkf
    <img src="https://example.com/43435565653554/687474703a2f2f736f757" alt="\\">
    <img src="https://example.com/22223445556565/687474703a2f243434344" alt="\\">
fgfgfgfgfgfgfgfgfgfg
    <center>
```

i want to remove last part of all link `687474703a2f2f736f757` and `687474703a2f243434344` as

```
    <center>
texttextffjfjfffkfkf
    <img src="https://example.com/43435565653554/" alt="\\">
    <img src="https://example.com/22223445556565/" alt="\\">
fgfgfgfgfgfgfgfgfgfg
    <center>
```

Comment: Will all links follow that format? If yes, then you could set up a RegEx to capture and replace

Comment: Are these img tags hard coded or generated by PHP

Comment: justCarty yes all links follow that format

Comment: After re-reading my comment and the question; it's clear I didn't fully understand the question. The RegEx approach is not a good one... Perhaps a `substr` would be a better approach

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

$input  = explode('/', 'https://example.com/43435565653554/687474703a2f2f736f757');
$output = implode('/', array_slice($input, 0, 4));
echo $output;
```

output: `https://example.com/43435565653554`

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

You can select sub-string in mysql

```
SELECT *, SUBSTRING(columnName, 1, CHAR_LENGTH(columnName)-numOfCharactoerYouWantToRemove) as temp FROM `user`
```

For example,

```
SELECT *, SUBSTRING(description, 1, CHAR_LENGTH(description)-2) as temp FROM `user`
```

Comment: not working this code

Comment: post your query that you are executing

Answer (score 0):

In php you can go with :

```
$testText = "https://example.com/43435565653554/687474703a2f2f736f757";
$testText = preg_replace('#(http.+/)[a-zA-Z0-9]+/?$#', '$1', $testText);
```

In javascript you can go with :

```
var testText = "https://example.com/43435565653554/687474703a2f2f736f757"
var newText = testText.replace(/(http.+\/)[a-zA-Z0-9]+\/?$/, "$1")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with regular expression. This is how you could do that in php.

```
$url='https://example.com/43435565653554/687474703a2f2f736f757';
$url= preg_replace('/([A-z]|\d)*$/', '', $url);
echo $url;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative: using `substr` and `strrpos`.

```
<?php
// Obtained from the database, hard coded for the sake of this question
$urls = [
    'https://example.com/43435565653554/687474703a2f2f736f757',
    'https://example.com/22223445556565/687474703a2f243434344'
];
?>
<center>
texttextffjfjfffkfkf
<?php foreach ($urls as $url) { ?>
    <img src="<?= substr($url, 0, strrpos(trim($url, " \t\n\r\0\x0B/"), '/')); ?>" alt="\\" />
<?php } ?>
fgfgfgfgfgfgfgfgfgfg
<center>
```

What this does is gets a substring from the start of the string and then gets the position of the last occurring `/`.

Since you stated that the format of these URLs will *always* be the same, you don't need to worry about any trailing `/`.
That being said, I used a trim with a custom mask to remove any leading or trailing `/`.